# Why WebGL in this code doesn't render a outlined rectangle?

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I'm noob to WebGL and tried to make outlined rectangle but in same time with using shaders that i mixed them :)

The problem is the code doesn't give errors, But doesn't render outlined rectangle with clearing, It's just clear and rectangle not rendered...

Here is vertex shader...

```
// VERTEX SHADER
attribute vec2 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
uniform vec2 u_translation;
uniform vec2 u_resolution; 
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
    vec2 zeroToOne = (a_position + u_translation) / u_resolution;
    vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
    vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
    gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Here is fragment shader...

```
// FRAGMENT SHADER
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D u_image;
uniform vec4 u_color;
uniform int u_mode;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main(void) {
    if (u_mode == 1) { gl_FragColor = u_color; }
    if (u_mode == 2) { gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
    if (u_mode == 3) { gl_FragColor = u_color + texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
}
```

Oh...And here is HTML file...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POLYGL Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
      // Get context
      var gl = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].getContext("webgl");

      // Create buffers for rectangle
      var x = 100, y = 100, w = 50, h = 50;
      var rect = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
          x, -y,
          x + w, -y,
          x + w, -(y + h),
          x, -(y + h),
      ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);

      // Create shaders and assign GLSL code for them...
      var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vs, `
        attribute vec2 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
        uniform vec2 u_translation;
        uniform vec2 u_resolution; 
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;
        void main() {
          vec2 zeroToOne = (a_position + u_translation) / u_resolution;
          vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
          vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
          gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
          v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
        }`);
       gl.compileShader(vs);

       var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
       gl.shaderSource(fs, `
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D u_image;
        uniform vec4 u_color;
        uniform int u_mode;
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;
        void main(void) {
            if (u_mode == 1) { gl_FragColor = u_color; }
            if (u_mode == 2) { gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
            if (u_mode == 3) { gl_FragColor = u_color + texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
        }`);
        gl.compileShader(fs);

        // Create program and link all
        var p = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(p, vs);
        gl.attachShader(p, fs);
        gl.linkProgram(p);
        gl.useProgram(p);
       
        // Delete shaders and program after being used...
        gl.deleteShader(vs);
        gl.deleteShader(fs);
        gl.deleteProgram(p);

        // Clear to black and set viewport
        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        // Set color, resolution, And translation...
        // Set mode to 1 so it only renders with gl_FragColor
        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_mode"), 1);
        gl.uniform4f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_color"), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
        gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_resolution"), gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
        gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_translation"), 0, 0);

        // Bind rectangle buffer
        // Enable vertex attribute and assign buffer to shaders...
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(p, "a_position"), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(p, "a_position"));
       
        // Draw!
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried even to remove deletions of programs but looks like it doesn't help...
Can anyone help me?

Comment: FYI, it's generally considered bad practice to put conditionals like `if (u_mode == 1)` in shaders. In fact it's likely to break. Instead you should make a different shader for each situation or else use some creative math so you don't need the conditionals. For example if you remove modes 1 and 2 and just have `gl_FragColor = u_color + texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);` then when you just want a solid color set `u_image` to 1x1 pixel white texture. When you just want a texture, set `u_color` to (1, 1, 1, 1). Also you might find [these articles](https://webglfundamentals.org) useful.

Comment: Thanks for advice...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, The indices aren't right cause height is negative, Fixed!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>POLYGL Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas width="600" height="600"></canvas>
    <script>
      var gl = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0].getContext("webgl");
      var x = 100, y = 100, w = 50, h = 50;
      var rect = gl.createBuffer();
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect);
      gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
          x, y,
          x + w, y,
          x + w, y + h,
          x, y + h,
      ]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
      gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        
      var vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
      gl.shaderSource(vs, `
        attribute vec2 a_position;
        attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
        uniform vec2 u_translation;
        uniform vec2 u_resolution; 
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;
        void main() {
          vec2 zeroToOne = (a_position + u_translation) / u_resolution;
          vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;
          vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;
          gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);
          v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
        }`);
       gl.compileShader(vs);

       var fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
       gl.shaderSource(fs, `
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D u_image;
        uniform vec4 u_color;
        uniform int u_mode;
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;
        void main(void) {
            if (u_mode == 1) { gl_FragColor = u_color; }
            if (u_mode == 2) { gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
            if (u_mode == 3) { gl_FragColor = u_color + texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord); }
        }`);
        gl.compileShader(fs);

        var p = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(p, vs);
        gl.attachShader(p, fs);
        gl.linkProgram(p);
        gl.useProgram(p);
        gl.deleteShader(vs);
        gl.deleteShader(fs);
        gl.deleteProgram(p);

        gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

        gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_mode"), 1);
        gl.uniform4f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_color"), Math.random(), Math.random(), Math.random(), 1);
        gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_resolution"), gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
        gl.uniform2f(gl.getUniformLocation(p, "u_translation"), 0, 0);
        
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, rect);
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(gl.getAttribLocation(p, "a_position"), 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(gl.getAttribLocation(p, "a_position"));
        gl.drawArrays(gl.LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```